# dataframe - find distinct value count by columns for rows of same value for one column

Tags: r

For the following sample data frame, I need to find for each `id`  - the count of distinct values for each column

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(2,2,3,3,3,1,1,4,4),
                         prop1 = c("A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C"),
                         prop2 = c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE),
                         prop3= c(4,4,3,3,4,5,1,5,1))
    > df
      id prop1 prop2 prop3
    1  2     A FALSE     4
    2  2     A FALSE     4
    3  3     B FALSE     3
    4  3     B FALSE     3
    5  3     B FALSE     4
    6  1     B  TRUE     5
    7  1     B FALSE     1
    8  4     B  TRUE     5
    9  4     C FALSE     1
```

base R preferred.

**Expected Output format**:

```
    > dfDistinctCountByProp
      id prop1.unq.cnt prop2.unq.cnt prop3.unq.cnt
    1  1        1               2         2
    2  2        1               1         1
    3  3        1               1         2
    4  4        2               2         2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `sum` the not-`duplicated` cases in `aggregate`, which lets you group by `id`:

```
aggregate(. ~ id, df, function(x){ sum(!duplicated(x)) })

##   id prop1 prop2 prop3
## 1  1     1     2     2
## 2  2     1     1     1
## 3  3     1     1     2
## 4  4     2     2     2
```

or use `length(unique(...))` if it makes more sense to you:

```
aggregate(. ~ id, df, function(x){length(unique(x))})    # returns identical result
```

Should a reader care, in dplyr it would be

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(n_distinct)
```

or data.table,

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN), by = id]
```